# Replace xscreensaver With gnome-screensaver (Xubuntu)

Tags: gdm, xubuntu, screensaver

I have recently `apt-get remove`'d xscreensaver and `apt-get install`'d gnome-screensaver. This appears not to have worked because when I press the Lock Screen menu item, nothing happens. I have tried putting gnome-screensaver in the list of autostart applications but this doesn't help (must it be started before anyone logs in?). How can I make gnome-screensaver work properly and make the Lock Screen button do what it's supposed to? Thanks in advance, ell.

EDIT: I am using Xubuntu 11.04 and the output of ps aux | grep saver is:

```
elliot    1374  0.0  0.3  27344  6024 ?        Ss   19:35   0:00 gnome-screensaver
elliot    1669  0.0  0.0   4160   848 pts/0    S+   19:48   0:00 grep --color=auto saver
```

But I think the above information will now be irrelevant as **it seems that locking the screen now works**, when I lock the screen I get a black screen and when I move the mouse, the unlock dialog pops up so now all I need to do is set a screensaver, can anyone help me out on that?

Comment: Is there an "outdated" tag for questions? light-locker should take care of this use-case in Xubuntu if all you want is screen blanking (except for on those systems where it's buggy, see bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/… ), while gnome-screensaver 1) also requires entering password twice, and 2) can't auto-lock on XFCE without also running gnome-session, see bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Installing

When you have removed `xscreensaver` and installed `gnome-screensaver` you will need to logout and login for the XFCE lock-screen menu item to work

### Setting your screen saver

Installing gnome-screensaver also installs `gnome-screensaver-preferences`.

If you run this in a terminal you will see this screen which will allow you to change from the "black screen" to one of the gnome-screensavers:

[image]

### Integrating with Settings Manager

When installing `gnome-screensaver` it will create a file called `/usr/share/applications/gnome-screensaver-preferences.desktop`

To integrate this into Settings Manager then replace the contents of this file with the following:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Screensaver
Comment=Set your screensaver preferences
Icon=preferences-desktop-screensaver
Exec=gnome-screensaver-preferences
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Settings;DesktopSettings;Security;X-XFCE
NotShowIn=KDE;GNOME;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `gnome-screensaver-preferences` is no longer shipped along with 12.04 (and up). So how does configuration take place now? I'm not that much concerned about fancy stuff, but e.g. configuring screen timeout.

Comment: @Izzy - try either http://askubuntu.com/questions/180793/how-can-i-set-a-global-timeout-for-the-screensaver or http://askubuntu.com/questions/99825/configuring-screen-timeout-lock-based-on-location

Comment: Thanks! The second one I definitly missed (no `screensaver` tag :) Will check them both. Still, I cannot understand why there's no user-friendly solution (or rather why that was removed)...

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to remove Xscreensaver. After you install `gnome-screensaver`, you can change the file `/usr/bin/xflock4` to give priority to grome-screensaver.

Install gnome-screensaver:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Open file:

```
sudo nano /usr/bin/xflock4
```

Find

```
# Lock by xscreensaver or gnome-screensaver, if a respective daemon is running
for lock_cmd in \
"xscreensaver-command -lock" \
"gnome-screensaver-command --lock"
```

Replace

```
for lock_cmd in \
"gnome-screensaver-command --lock" \
"xscreensaver-command -lock"
```

May need logging out and in again.

Comment: how do you manage to get into the settings of gnome screensaver, as gnome-screensaver-preferences does not seem to exist anymore? thx

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer this question, since I don't use Xfce anymore...