# How can I set a global timeout for the screensaver?

Tags: 12.04, unity, screensaver, administration

I am trying to to set a global screensaver and blanking idle timout (with screen locking) that will affect all new user accounts. I noticed that gnome-screensaver in 12.04 when configured by a user, writes some data to a blob in ~/.dconf, but I have no idea how to set it globally. I also know that the global timeout is 10 minutes with blanking, but have no idea where this is set system wide. I find the whole dconf transition a bit difficult.

If it is not possible to configure gnome-screensaver this way, I would be quite interested in a solution with xscreensaver/xlock.

The purpose of this is to set a blank screen with automatic locking. Both because of resource usage and security.

Forgot to mention that this is a default Ubuntu 12.04 desktop install with Unity and LightDM. I will however install gnome-shell and gnome-session-fallback to let people choose. It would be nice if a solution works across different sessions.

Answer (score 8):

### Which dconf keys are used

To know which keys are changed in dconf, you can use `dconf watch /` while changing settings. In this case, you'll see something like :

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-ac
  1800

/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-battery
  1800

/org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay
  uint32 1800
```

Then, you put these keys in a file in `/etc/dconf`.

### Create and activate `/etc/dconf`

If this directory does not exists, you have to create it and activate its use with these commands :

```
mkdir -p /etc/dconf/profile /etc/dconf/db/local.d
cat <<EOF >/etc/dconf/profile/user
user-db:user
system-db:local
EOF
```

cf: https://live.gnome.org/dconf/SystemAdministrators

### Put your global settings

Use a file in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d` named, for example, `screensaver-delay`:

```
[org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power]
sleep-display-ac=1800
sleep-display-battery=1800

[org/gnome/desktop/session]
idle-delay=1800
```

Apply it running the command: `dconf update`. It will (re)generate the file `/etc/dconf/db/local` which will be used if keys do not conflict with user defined values.

### Force global values

If you want to force these global values over user selected values, you can do it by using a file in `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks` named, for example, `screensaver-delay`:

```
# Force screensaver delay
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-ac
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/power/sleep-display-battery
/org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay
```

Comment: The line with `cat <EOF` should be `cat <<EOF` (bash "here-documents").

Answer (score 2):

xscreensaver option (tested on Xubuntu 12.04): Edit `/etc/X11/app-defaults/XScreenSaver` (as root) to set `lock` to `True` and `lockTimeout` to whatever time you want.  This will change the default for all users, but the users can still change it using the normal preference mechanism.

Comment: This solution is still valid for Xubuntu 18.04