# Reduce screensaver timeout to a custom value in seconds

Tags: unity, screensaver, timeout

I have a box running ubuntu 13.10 unity that I need to auto log in and it currently locks after 30 seconds, but I'd like to reduce this to between 1 and 5 seconds - how can I do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you can set the timeout of `gnome-screensaver` (used by Ubuntu) with *System Settings -> Brightness & Lock*. However, this GUI only supports setting 1 minute at the minimum. For a delay between 1 and 5 seconds we need to set this manually.

You can use `dconf watch /` to watch all settings that are being changed.

If you issue that command, then open the *Brightness & Lock* panel and change the setting for *Turn screen off when inactive for...*, you will see an output like this:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay
  uint32 180
```

Hence, in order to set it to a value of for example 5 seconds, issue the command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/session/idle-delay "uint32 5"
```

Source & more information: [How can I set a global timeout for the screensaver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180793/how-can-i-set-a-global-timeout-for-the-screensaver)

Comment: That's ace thanks, it works, but (next question :S) is there any way to reduce the time the screen takes to fade?

Comment: I don't think that there is such a feature. The time the screen takes to fade is presumably more or less hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Such things can be directly controlled with `gsettings`. For example to get a list of all the screensaver settings available to tweak:

```
gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.screensaver
```

**Ajusting lock delay after screen fade:**

You should be able to adjust the lock delay (this is time *after* blanking that locking occurs) with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-delay uint32 5
```

to give you a 5 second delay before lock.

**Adjusting the fade screen delay itself (blank screen time):**

You can set

```
gsettings org.gnome.desktop.session idle-delay uint32 5
```

which I is the blank screen time (time for screen to fade), to give a 5 second fade for example.