# Replacing xscreensaver with gnome-screensaver, problems(Xubuntu)

Tags: xubuntu, lock-screen, xscreensaver, gnome-screensaver

I found this helpful question [Replace xscreensaver With gnome-screensaver (Xubuntu)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59577/replace-xscreensaver-with-gnome-screensaver-xubuntu) but the executable `gnome-screensaver-preferences` can't be found. So I'm not sure what to do, to get `gnome-screensaver` working correctly.

How do I configure it if that program isn't there?

Comment: Messing with the screensaver in ubuntu is a sure way to bork it up.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a very late reply but hopefully someone still finds it useful. Ubuntu 12.04 and newer releases have [no configuration tool](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=316654) for Gnome's screensaver as it is more a screen blanker than an actual screensaver.

Gnome's developers are not willing to change this, so you may want revert back to xscreensaver, which has a graphical configuration tool. Please see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/64086/8973) if you need help with getting xscreensaver back.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening Terminal (By pressing Control + Alt + 'T') and then typing in 'sudo apt-get remove gnome-screensaver gnome-screensaver-preferences xscreensaver' 
Then once it's finished, type 'sudo apt-get -f install'. 
Then try installing gnome-screensaver again. 
I am sure there is at least one or two third party programs that you could use to customize gnome-screensaver. 
You could also look in the program 'synaptic' and search for 'gnome-screensaver' and 'xscreensaver', then reinstall gnome-screensaver if required.